# How to get database table data(oracle 11g) as an Json object & to display that Json object in Android?

Tags: java, android, json, oracle, servlets

I am trying to create a connection between android app and oracle DB. I found that I have to create a web service, so I started writing a servlet which would crate a connection with database and return the data as JSON object which can be parsed on android.
To start with I wrote a servlet to return data in HTML format which was pretty easy, following is my servlet code

```
package a.b.c;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletDatabaseConnect extends HttpServlet  
{
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        PrintWriter pw=res.getWriter();
        res.setContentType("text/html");        
        String tb=req.getParameter("table");    

        try
        {
             Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
             Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","system","admin");
             Statement st=con.createStatement();
             System.out.println("connection established successfully...!!");     

             ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("Select * from "+tb);

             pw.println("<table border=1>");
                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                     pw.println("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>"+
                                      "<td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td></tr>");
                 }
             pw.println("</table>");
             pw.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

How do I modify my servlet code to return the data in JSON object format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I found my own answer I used JSON-simple-1.1.jar it is available for free on java2s.com

```
following is my servlet code now

package servlet.package1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;




@WebServlet("/ServletTalk")
public class ServletTalk extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public ServletTalk() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    }

 // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();


        //ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

        String[] params = new String[2];
        int i = 0;
        while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String) paramNames.nextElement();


            //System.out.println(paramName);
            String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            params[i] = paramValues[0];

            //System.out.println(params[i]);
            i++;

        }

        String sql = "SELECT LOGIN_ID, PASSWORD FROM SE_USER where LOGIN_ID=? and PASSWORD=?";
        Connection con = getConnection();

        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, params[0]);
            ps.setString(2, params[1]);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                json.put("info", "success");
                /*String sql1 = "SELECT uname, password FROM users";
                PreparedStatement ps2=con.prepareStatement(sql1);
                ResultSet rs2=ps2.executeQuery();
                JSONArray arrayJSON=new JSONArray();
                while(rs2.next())
                {
                    JSONObject arrayObject = new JSONObject();
                    arrayObject.put("userName", rs2.getString("uname"));
                    arrayObject.put("passWord", rs2.getString("password"));
                    arrayJSON.add(arrayObject);
                }


                json.put("IDS",arrayJSON);*/
            } else {
                json.put("info", "fail");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(json);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //json.put("info", disp);
        response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
    }

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");//Mysql Connection
        //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");//Oracle Connection
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServletTalk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/a9613246_mydata1", "root", "root");//mysql database
        //con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "hemabh_demo", "hemabh_demo");//oracle database

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServletTalk.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return con;
}



}
```

the returned JSON is not formatted properly but can be parsed easily without any external libraries like Gson, etc.

Was fun finding the answer ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Jackson to transform your information in json format, this action is called serialization and Jackson is the perfect tool to do this task, you can see some examples [here](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/)

Comment: can u provide some tutorials links please... since i am a beginer  in all this

Comment: check this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/  but instead of use the method mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), user); use the method mapper.writeValueasString(user)